# Alternative $_POST method in PHP in Getting Values of a Button in a loop condition

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP so I am in need of your help.

My table in web is in a loop so it gets values in my mySQL phpMyAdmin database until it reaches the end of the database table.

I have a problem getting the desired value I want to show up in my table when certain button is pressed. Once I pressed a single button, it actually shows up the value of it, **BUT, IT SHOWS THE OTHER BUTTON'S VALUE AS WELL**.

In my conclusion, I think my $_POST code is missing something or is a complete mistake.

The code is here:

```
<tr>
   <?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
           $exerciseid = $row['exerciseid'];
            $question = $row['question'];
            $a = $row['answera'];
            $b = $row['answerb'];
            $c = $row['answerc'];
            $correctanswer = $row['answer'];
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $question?></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $a?>" name="a-submit">A. <?php echo $a?></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $b?>" name="b-submit">B. <?php echo $b?></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $c?>" name="c-submit">C. <?php echo $c?></button></td>
    <td><?php 
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
            if(isset($_POST['a-submit'])){
                echo $a;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST['b-submit'])){
                echo $b;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST['c-submit'])){
                echo $c;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

What do you think is the possible cause of my mistake? Please help

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, all your buttons are in single form that's why you are getting all the buttons value when you click any button.

I am not sure why you need post here because, if you want to get the button value you can simply get it using jQuery.

Check my sample code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Question <?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-answer" value="Answer 1" rel="question<?php echo $i; ?>" name="a-submit">A. Answer 1</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-answer" value="Answer 2" rel="question<?php echo $i; ?>" name="b-submit">B. Answer 2</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-answer" value="Answer 3" rel="question<?php echo $i; ?>" name="c-submit">C. Answer 3</button></td>
            <td class="question<?php echo $i; ?>-answ"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-answer').on('click', function () {
            $('.' + $(this).attr('rel') + '-answ').html($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

class "`btn-answer`" -> global class for all answer buttons to call jquery click action

`rel` -> to identify the question

`question<?php echo $i; ?>-answ` -> to identify the answer block the show the user selection

Comment: I'm looking for a PHP code but I'll check this one after my morning grind. Will comment back here later

Comment: sure, let me know if you need any info

Comment: hey, this works and solves my problem! Will try to translate this myself to PHP and see if I can do. If not, a big thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, do "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>" needs internet access right? I somehow need it with the access of the internet

Comment: Hi, you can use your local jQuery path

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice. I'll be working on it back after the holidays, Cheers and have a happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the same variable name within a loop, and display the value that was submitted by user, you could do it like below :

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $question?></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $a?>" name="a-submit">A. <?php echo $a?></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $b?>" name="b-submit">B. <?php echo $b?></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $c?>" name="c-submit">C. <?php echo $c?></button></td>
    <td><?php 
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
            if(isset($_POST["a-submit"]) && $_POST["a-submit"] == $a){
                echo $a;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST["b-submit"]) && $_POST["b-submit"] == $b){
                echo $b;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST["c-submit"]) && $_POST["c-submit"] == $c){
                echo $c;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But this will not prevent multiple answer from being shown because no unique id been given on each variable (for example if there are question which having the same answer).

Comment: I can add unique variable to each of them, but it'll lose the purpose of having a loop since i cannot loop unique variables

Comment: Could you describe in more detail of what are you trying to achieve? could you show the current result you get?

Comment: The questions and answers I'm getting is a user-inputted, they're not hard coded. So my code I posted gets that questions and answers inputted by the user in the database is in a loop so that it can retrieve as long as how many have the user submitted in the database. So if I give each a unique variables, meaning I cannot use the loop and I'll have to hard code each time the user adds questions and answers to the database. So the easiest way will be in a loop getting all that from the database

Comment: Here's a picture to show my problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7SuubWPrNmEynt8LomjKi-p9ULtXudt/view?usp=sharing

On that picture, I choose to answer on the first row. So the correct answer would be letter b, which is 2. It shows correctly what I've selected BUT, it also shows other letter b of other questions. I hope that makes things more clearly

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and somehow, it may show the answers but when i go press onto the other button's question, my former answer shown goes empty. I'll be trying a different approach but as holiday is nearing, i'll take a short break. I'll be updating soonest as possible after the holiday. thanks and happy holidays!

Comment: The simple answer is, you can't. If you want persistence, then you have to use some storage method, like session.